# how to speed up repetitive java tasks

Tags: java, performance, jvm

Suppose you need to run

```
java myprog.class a
java myprog.class b
...
```

over and over again, and in that order, without using parallel threads. Everytime you invoke "java", jvm has to start from fresh, "myprog.class" has to be loaded into memory, ...

The question is: is there a simple way to speed this up easily? You can write a java program to handle the requests at one shot, i.e. to handle "a" "b" input values at a single request, and that can at least save the time to invoke jvm over and over again. But this requires another program to be written. Is there some other simple ways to speed up the repetitive requests?

Comment: Want to keep on running similar class in same vm instance? Have an entry class, that keeps on calling different classes.

Comment: Java `main` methods are methods like any other. Nothing stops you from invoking `myprog`'s main method from another class, passing in the `a`, `b` etc as you require.

Comment: Add a main class which calls `myprog` repeatedly, or change `myprog` to accept multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess calling myprog's method is the way to go. Thanks for the replies.